# Why is PROMPT_COMMAND declared as array in bashrc

Tags: bash

This is a snippet from a bash-5 /etc/bashrc

I don't understand why PROMPT_COMMAND is declared as an array:

```
declare -a PROMPT_COMMAND
```

```
# are we an interactive shell?
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
    if [ -z "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ]; then
      declare -a PROMPT_COMMAND
      case $TERM in
      xterm*)
        if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm ]; then
            PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm
        else
            PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"'
        fi
        ;;
      screen*)
        if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen ]; then
            PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen
        else
            PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033k%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"'
        fi
        ;;
      *)
        [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-default ] && PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-default
        ;;
      esac
    fi
```

Comment: See the section on [PROMPT_COMMAND](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PROMPT_005fCOMMAND) in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Comment: pjh: Thank you.

PROMPT_COMMAND
If this variable is set, and is an array, the value of each set element is interpreted as a command to execute before printing the primary prompt ($PS1). If this is set but not an array variable, its value is used as a command to execute instead.

Comment: pjh: do you want credit for providing the correct answer?

Comment: In which bash version was this array version of PROMPT_COMMAND first supported?

Comment: It changed after this feature request https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2018-02/msg00076.html

Comment: Even though you declared it as an array, you assigned strings to it. So it's always a 1-element array, and there's no difference in the behavior.

Comment: ...and consequently, `declare -a` in this particular `.bashrc` has no meaningful effect at all. (This is in keeping with my general grudge about "please explain this code someone else wrote" questions -- often that code is just bad/wrong/meaningless; Stack Overflow is only for questions about _specific problems you actually face_, and having some 3rd-party code that's basically a noop doesn't constitute facing a problem).

Comment: I guess you don't ask why it *can* be an array (which is explained in the bash man-page), but why the author of your script *decides* to declare it as array. IMO this does not make sense, because the variable is assigned as a scalar. I would remove the array declaration.

Comment: As an argument *against* removing it, there's no harm to making it an array but not using any additional "slots" at this time. Users can write `PROMPT_COMMAND[1]=...`, etc, if they like in their own `.bashrc` files, without the (admittedly minor) obstacle of (re)declaring `declare -a PROMPT_COMMAND` themselves.

Comment: From Chet Ramey: "Bash-5.1 release available"
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2020-12/msg00002.html

"The PROMPT_COMMANDS array variable can be used to run multiple commands before printing the primary prompt"